# Can I use docker for installing ubuntu on a Mac?

Tags: docker

I'm using a Mac, but I want to learn and use Ubuntu for development and I don't care about the GUI. I used to use Vagrant and ssh to the machine, but it consumes much of my machine resources.  Can I use docker for the same purpose while also having the isolation (when I mess things up) of a VM?

Comment: Ubuntu Server running in a VM will take like 512MiB of RAM, 10GiB disk space, and next to zero CPU while idle (I use 14.04 LTS). Docker will probably only reduce the disk usage.

Comment: If you want to use ubuntu specifically.... Rather go with Multipass from Canonical. You would compromise the GUI but it's worth it!!

Answer (score 80):

- First install [Docker Desktop for Mac](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop).
- Then in a terminal window run: `docker run -it --name ubuntu ubuntu:xenial bash`

You are in a terminal with ubuntu and can do whatever you like.

> **Note:** If you are using an ubuntu version bionic (18.04) or newer (`ubuntu:bionic` or `ubuntu:latest`), you
>   must run the command `unminimize` inside the container so the tools
>   for human interaction be installed.

To start again after a reboot:

```
docker start ubuntu
docker exec -it ubuntu bash
```

If you want save your changes:

```
docker commit ubuntu
docker images
```

See the unnamed image and:

`docker tag <imageid> myubuntu`

Then you can run another container using your new image.

`docker run -it --name myubuntu myubuntu bash`

Or replace the former

```
docker stop ubuntu
docker rm ubuntu
docker run -it --name ubuntu myubuntu bash
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried this, but sudo doesn't work here. Nor add-apt-repository

Comment: You don't need sudo, it runs with root user. For full Ubuntu experience you need to run the command "unminimize"

Comment: This version of command above is so host and container can share a volume: `docker run --mount type=bind,source=/Users/myName/Desktop/data,target=/data -it --name ubuntu ubuntu:bionic bash` per link here: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34532

Answer (score 16):

This is one of the few scenarios I wouldn't use Docker for :)

Base images like [Ubuntu](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/) are heavily stripped down versions of the full OS. The latest Ubuntu image doesn't have basic tools like `ping` and `curl` - that's a deliberate strategy from Canonical to minimise the size of the image, and therefore the attack vector. Typically you'd build an image to run a single app process in a container, you wouldn't SSH in and use ordinary dev tools, so they're not needed. That will make it hard for you to learn Ubuntu, because a lot of the core stuff isn't there.

On the Mac, the best VM tool I've used is [Parallels](https://www.parallels.com/eu/landingpage/pd/general/?gclid=COmDyezY5M8CFYefGwodEB0M2w) - it manages to share CPU without hammering the battery. [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) is good too, and for either of them you can install full [Ubuntu Server](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server) from the ISO - 5GB disk and 1GB RAM allocation will be plenty if you're just looking around.

With any hypervisor you can pause VMs so they stop using resources, and checkpoint them to save the image so you can restore back to it later.

Comment: That's probably a better solution... Using something free like VirtualBox to run Ubuntu is probably less overhead than running Docker (which then uses a VM under the hood to run Ubuntu).

Comment: Virtualbox does not support Apple M1, and Parallels does not support running x86 VM on M1 host; Docker does.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can.

Try searching docker hub for ubuntu containers of your choice (version and who is supporting the image)

Most of them are very well documented on what was used to build it and also how to run and access/expose resources if needed.

Check the official one here: https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/

Comment: One thing to note, though: Both Vagrant and Docker-Machine (or Docker for Mac) run a virtual machine (VirtualBox in most cases) that will block some of the host system's resources. Depending on how you scale that VM, you will see an impact on your host system's performance. If you only have 4 GB of RAM, and you give 3 GB to Vagrant or Docker-Machine, you will notice that. If you have 16 GB of RAM in your machine, you can be more generous...

Comment: And what happens when I "rm -rf /" in the guest? :)

Comment: @HorusCoding rm will behave like you are used to on a VM

Comment: @nwinkler Oh so there will be no gain in my case?

Comment: Don't know, I suggest you give it a try. You said you don't care about the UI, so running a "headless" Ubuntu will take up less resources than one with a full X server. Without knowing your hardware specs, it's hard to tell.

Comment: @HorusCoding there are some advantages like space used in disk, boot time, ability to easily test on different different SO versions

Comment: Hello @nwinkler, Docker for Mac doesn't use docker-machine anymore. This product is called Docker Toolbox. Docker for Mac uses a very efficient virtualization solution which integrates better with MacOS and consumes less resources